# Firefox bookmarks toolbar option is missing

Tags: 16.04, firefox

Several days ago I noticed that "Hide bookmarks toolbar" option is missing, I used to use this option when I right click at the top of the Firefox window. Then I tried to hide it by clicking on View -> Toolbars and then I should uncheck the Bookmarks toolbar but it's missing here too. When I click on Customize I used to see Bookmarks toolbar at the bottom of the page under Toolbars menu item, but I can't see it here too.

I tried restarting without addons and I also refreshed the Firefox, didn't help.

This question is originally posted on Firefox support so I'll paste the link in case someone needs some info: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1209543

Comment: Have the option here in Firefox 59.0.1 from the repositories on Xubuntu 16.04. Just tested the option, works as expected. Also works in Ubuntu mate 17.10.

Comment: I tried deleting and installing again the Firefox from repositories but still the same issue. Snap version of Firefox has issues with themes so I can't use that, but bookmarks toolbar works fine.

Comment: I submitted a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1758107) regarding this exact issue. It includes a [video](https://youtu.be/Josm0VqtUDQ) showcasing the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>I've been facing the same problem (no more bookmark toolbar and no option to enable it by right-clicking on the main toolbar like there used to be). Thought of a problem with the new version (as the problem occurred after last update for me) but my wife found a way to enable the bookmark toolbar.</sub>

You need to **add the bookmark item to the main toolbar**, click on it, select "Bookmarks toolbar" ("Barre personnelle" in French, could be a slightly different label), then check "**Display the bookmarks toolbar**".

See here what I'm talking about (in French):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked, but still it's an issue which should be fixed, I can't always add bookmark to hide/show bookmarks toolbar

Comment: I agree:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1758107