# Snap Firefox can't access to disks in /mnt; Repository Firefox doesn't have bookmark toolbar

Tags: apt, firefox, snap

I've previously used Firefox in a Ubuntu 16.04 system (upgraded from the 14.04) without any problems. However, I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 in a different disk and wanted to use Firefox as my browser, but I have two problems:

- If I use the default repository's Firefox (`sudo apt-get install firefox`), I cannot use the bookmarks toolbar. Let me be clear: the issue is not that it isn't visible, but that it does not appear under View>Toolbars or in the Customize window (in both cases, the "Toolbars" menu is empty)
- If I snap-install Firefox (`sudo snap install firefox`), everything works perfectly fine, but I cannot access to data in other disks or disk partitions in my computer. For example, when I try to upload an email with a file in a different disk or partition, it says it has no permissions to do so.

Solving any of these problems would be very helpful. In particular (because it may be easier to answer), is it possible to grant a snap application the permission to access to other partitions of the disk? Or the whole purpose of the snap packages is that precisely this is not possible, and there is no way around it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your first issue is a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015697/firefox-bookmarks-toolbar-option-is-missing/1016931) and you can mark yourself as affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1758107).

To fix your second issue, run the command `sudo snap connect firefox:removable-media`, GNOME Software in Ubuntu 18.04 supports doing this from the app, rather than via Terminal, but this will have to do for now!

If you feel this is a feature that users should have by default, you could [file an auto-connection request](https://forum.snapcraft.io/c/store) tagging @osomon for confirmation that this is a good idea :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
As far as I understand, in order for `sudo snap connect firefox:removable-media` to work, I also need to change the mount point of the disk from /mnt to /media, or am I wrong? 
In any case, I've been using the repository version of Firefox, I managed to make the bookmark toolbar visible by adding a new bookmark to the bar... It's not pretty, but worked! Hope they fix this thing, though...

Comment: Thank you ! i had the same problem with keepassXc and just by connecting /mnt to the snap, it works like a sharm !